# How to share Account record to customer community user

Tags: customer-community

We are in the process of setting up customer community.  We have a custom object with read/write access to customer community users. This custom object has a lookup to Account. Sharing settings for this custom object is set to Private and through sharing rules we have given R/W access to Internal users.

When the customer community user creates a new custom object record, for Account lookup, they should be able to select only their Account (for which their contact record is setup with). In the communities, we used the sharing set on Account (User:Account = Account:Id), but even then the community user cannot see any Account records on the lookup of the custom object record.

Can anyone provide directions on how do we share Account records to customer community users. ( they should be able to see only their Account)

Comment: This [Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AtsAIAS) should give you a direction.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the linke.. I have created the below sharing set.

User:Contact.Account = Account:Id

I have a customer community user and his corresponding contact record (C1) is associated with a Account (A1).

When I login as the community user and try to create a new custom obeject record (which has a look up to Account), I can still cant see any Accouts in the search results. I was hoping to see Account A1, which the community user should now have access because of the sharing set created. 

Can you please let me know if am doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned on the enhanced lookup under Setup -> Customize -> Search -> Search Settings. Now when I login as Community user, I can see only my Account in the Account lookup on the custom object record.